# NavigationController is showing another view controller instead of pushing viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have main ViewController which is named ViewController(if i run my project it runs firstly). If i push my DetailViewController, it is showing my ViewController view.

Here is my part of code:

AppDelegate.m

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:Nil bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:NULL];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Tell me where's your view is built.it's in view controller.

Comment: inside of View Controller,  DetailViewcontroller is my second view which is i want to show, when i push from inside of from ViewController

Comment: your question doesn t make sense, how can you push your view in viewController.h

Comment: i couldnt explain my problem. i have button in ViewController's view. if i touch it, it must show another view(DetailViewController's view). But it didnt. it showed ViewController's view again

Comment: - (void) hello
{
    DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 50, 50)];
    [btn setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(hello) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following code

```
DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: download following test project
[link](https://github.com/chathurka/sharedProject)

Answer (score 0):

In your Button's Action, implement this

```
DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

You are not initializing with its `nib` file

Comment: i think, i have another problem too. when i changed with this, i took runtime error

Comment: Did you clean your project?

Comment: Go to `Product` in the menu bar of `XCode` and select `clean` menu item for the `project`.

Comment: Did your `DetailViewController` does not contain any nib files? @AyubxonUbaydullayev

Comment: sorry, what are nib files. I am new in ios

Comment: The `.xib` files which are attached to `ViewController`

Comment: i allocated my DetailViewController's view, then it showed. Before it was showing, my mistake was that i didnt put anything in my view(DetailViewController's view). when i changed myBackGroundColor, my view's color changed.

Comment: So, now its all perfect. Is my answer wrong in thats perspective?

Comment: i dont understand your question fully. Could you give me link of any sites or books. Which i can learn objective C perfetcly

Comment: I just want to say that whether my answer provide you the solution?